# Pygame splash screen crashes game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, splash-screen

***This has been edited, the original post was about blitting the splash screens***
I'm working on a simple game using pygame, the game is almost complete however i'm having some issues with the splash screen. The current issue is that when the game is run, the splash screens blit like they are supposed to, however if the user clicks anywhere on the screen or tries to exit the game, it crashes. Does anybody know a way around this issue, what i am hoping for is that the user would even be able to exit the game or even skip the splash screen whilst they are being displayed.

```
def main():
    '''Here the game is being initialised'''
    pygame.init() #Initialising Pygame
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 20) #Registers event every 20MS if a key is held down
    countFont = pygame.font.Font(None,18) #Font being set
    statusFont = pygame.font.Font(None,18) #Font being set
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT]) 
    pygame.display.set_caption('Do Not Get Capped')

    #Drawable surface
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

    #Used for converting color maps
    background = background.convert()

    #Splashscreen

    #image fades in
    for i in range (225):
            background.fill((0,0,0))
            image = pygame.image.load("splash_screen1.png")
            image.set_alpha(i)
            logoimage = screen.blit(image,(0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.time.delay(2000)

    for i in range (225):
            background.fill((0,0,0))
            image = pygame.image.load("splash_screen2.png")
            image.set_alpha(i)
            logoimage = screen.blit(image,(0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.time.delay(4000)        

    '''The main function which is called at the end of this code'''
    class Game():
            '''This class's purpose is to keep track of the current score'''
            def __init__(self):
                    self.score=0
                    self.goalNumbers=0

    class Gun(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 
            '''This is the gun that the user controls'''
            def __init__(self): 
                    '''This is the class contructor'''
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                    self.image=pygame.image.load("turret.png") #Loading the gun's image
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect() #Getting the image's Rect
                    self.rect.x = 240 #Setting the rect's X position
                    self.rect.y = 630 #Setting the rect's Y position

            def moveGun(self,orientation):
                    '''This function allows the gun to move on the screen.
                        If the orientation is facing left and the gun is 5 pixels
                         away from the wall, the gun is moved left & vice-a-versa'''
                    if orientation=="left" and self.rect.x>5: 
                            self.rect.x-=5
                    if orientation=="right" and self.rect.x<(480-self.rect.width):
                            self.rect.x+=5

    class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            '''This class sets up the projectile/bullets that are controlled
                by the user'''
            def __init__(self,gun):
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                    self.image=pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
                    self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
                    '''The code below places the projectile on top of the gun'''
                    self.rect.x=gun.rect.x+(gun.rect.width/2)-(self.rect.width/2)
                    self.rect.y=gun.rect.y-gun.rect.height

            def updateProjectile(self):
                    '''This checks if the projectile has reached the top of the screen
                        if it hasn't it will continue to move up. If it has it will be deleted'''
                    if self.rect.y>0-self.rect.height:
                            self.rect.y-=5
                    else:
                            self.kill()

    class Objects(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            '''This class creates the objects, they are loaded from the computer
                and assigned to variables'''
            def __init__(self):
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                    self.obj=random.randint(1,3) 
                    if self.obj==1: imagefile="capped"
                    if self.obj==2: imagefile="notcapped1"
                    if self.obj==3: imagefile="notcapped2"
                    self.image=pygame.image.load(imagefile+".png")
                    self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.y=-0-self.rect.height
                    self.rect.x=(random.randint(2,44)*10)

            def updateProjectile(self,game):
                    '''This function allows for the objects to move down the screen'''
                    if self.rect.y<640:
                            self.rect.y+=7 #This controls the amount of pixels the objects move down thus contrlling the speed
                    else:
                            if self.obj==1:
                                    '''Here the code is tracking the users score'''
                                    game.score+=10 #This adds 10 to the game's score
                                    game.goalNumbers+=1 
                            else:
                                    game.score-=50
                            self.kill()

            def shot(self,game):
                    '''This function updates the score as well as removing the objects when they are hit by a projectile'''
                    if self.obj == 1:
                            game.score-=50
                    else:
                            game.score+=10
                    self.kill()


    # Create initial object instances
    '''Here i am creating objects based on the classes i created'''
    game=Game()
    gun=Gun()
    sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()
    sprites.add(gun)
    obstacles=pygame.sprite.Group()
    projectiles=pygame.sprite.Group()
    '''This variable will be used to control when to come out of the loop, i will state when this happens belows'''
    finish=False
    clock=pygame.time.Clock() #Initialising the clock
    tick=0

    '''This is the start of the main while loop, this loop will continue
        until the variable 'finish' becomes false'''
    while finish == False:
            clock.tick(30) #Loop will run 30 times a second
            tick+=1
            screen.fill(bColour)

            '''Here the main events are being run'''
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type==pygame.QUIT: 
                            '''If the user clicks the exit button, the finish variable is made True,
                                this means that rather than exiting the game, the user's score is displayed after
                                 which the game closes'''
                            finish = True
                    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            '''Here the script is checking for KEYDOWN events, these are events triggered
                                when the user presses on a keyboard key. In this case events are triggered when the left, right 
                                 and space keys are pressed.'''
                            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                                    gun.moveGun("left") #If this is activated the 'orientation' changes to 'left' which shunts the gun 5 pixels to the left
                            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                    gun.moveGun("right") #'Orientation' changes to 'right' which shunts the gun 5 pixels to the right
                            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                                    '''This triggers the projectiles function'''
                                    projectile=Projectile(gun)
                                    projectiles.add(projectile)       

            '''This controls the projectiles and objects moving around the window'''
            for projectile in projectiles:
                    projectile.updateProjectile()

            for obstacle in obstacles:
                    obstacle.updateProjectile(game)

            if tick>60: 
                    '''This controls at what rate the objects fall which is now once every two
                        seconds, this is because the loop runs in 30 second intervals and the 
                         clock is ticking at 60 seconds'''
                    if len(obstacles)<10:
                            obstacle=Objects()
                            obstacles.add(obstacle)
                    tick=0

            collisions=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(obstacles,projectiles,False,True)
            '''Here the script is checking whether the objects are hit by a projectile
               if they are, the 'shot' function is triggered'''
            if collisions: 
                    for obstacle in collisions:
                            obstacle.shot(game)

            '''This block of code constantly updates the player's scores'''                
            scoreText=countFont.render('Your current score is:'+str(game.score),True,(255,255,255),bColour)
            screen.blit(scoreText,(0,620))
            statusText=statusFont.render('You have '+str(10-game.goalNumbers)+' more tries',True,(255,255,255),bColour)
            screen.blit(statusText,(0,10))

            '''This code below updates and blits the objects to the screen'''
            sprites.draw(screen)
            projectiles.draw(screen)
            obstacles.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            if game.goalNumbers>=10: 
                    '''This if statement is checking whether 'obj1' has touched the floor 10 times
                        and if it did, the finish variable is made true thus ending the game'''
                    finish=True

    '''This is the last piece of code visible to the user,
        what happens here is that the final message showing the final score is shown'''
    scoreCountHolder=pygame.image.load("scoreframe.png")
    scoreCountHolder.convert_alpha()
    left=90
    top=250
    screen.blit(scoreCountHolder,(left,top))
    countFont=pygame.font.Font(None,52)
    statusText=countFont.render('Your Score:'+str(game.score),True,bColour,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(statusText,(105,300))
    pygame.display.flip() 

    while True: 
            '''This waits for the user to quit the game'''
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                            sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        '''The main function being called'''
        main()
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this kind of question; StackOverflow prefers specific, very focused, reusable technical questions (where others can easily learn from the question and its answers without wading through unrelated cruft). A SSCCE and a more specific explanation of "crashes" (do you have a stack trace? Which signal is it killed with? etc) would make this a more appropriate SO question.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a pygame application, you take all events from the input queue.

The operating system, adds new events onto the queue, while your application removes them.

Since you do not remove the events, the operating system thinks that your application froze.

To fix this, you should call `pygame.event.pump()`

From the pygame docs:

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call
>   to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact
>   with the rest of the operating system. If you are not using other
>   event functions in your game, you should call pygame.event.pump() to
>   allow pygame to handle internal actions.
>
> This function is not necessary if your program is consistently
>   processing events on the queue through the other pygame.eventpygame
>   module for interacting with events and queues functions.
>
> There are important things that must be dealt with internally in the
>   event queue. The main window may need to be repainted or respond to
>   the system. If you fail to make a call to the event queue for too
>   long, the system may decide your program has locked up.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you put a frame, Pygame then expects you to take the events that happened in the mean time out of its event queue. If you don't the OS thinks, that application got stuck!

You need to handle the events while you show the splash screen, if you want to allow the user to skip the flash screen.

Here's a way around that problem, it allows you to add specific event handling for splash screen:

```
class SplashScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Use numbers for ordering, make them continuous.
        self.image_dict = {
            1: "splash_screen1.png",
            2: "splash_screen2.png",
        }
        # Current image we are on!
        self.current_index = min(self.image_dict)
        # Last image
        self.end_index = max(self.image_dict)

        # Minimum alpha value
        self.alpha_min = 0
        # Maximum alpha value
        self.alpha_max = 225
        # Current alpha value
        self.alpha = self.alpha_min

        self.show = True

    # I leave it to you to figure out this function.
    def get_image(self):
        image_name = self.image_dict[self.current_index]
        image = pygame.image.load(image_name)
        image.set_alpha(self.alpha)
        self.alpha += 1
        if self.alpha > self.alpha_max:
            self.alpha = self.alpha_min
            self.current_index += 1
            if self.current_index == self.end_index:
                self.show = False
        return image


splash_screen = SplashScreen()

while True:
    # The ever-green event handling loop!
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...

    if splash_screen.show:
        # Splash screen stuff, one frame at a time
        background.fill((0, 0, 0))
        img = splash_screen.get_image()
        screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    else:
        # Game stuff, no need to call display.flip here, called at the end.
        ...

    # Called at the end after frame is ready!
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**Left as an exercise**
You should load and add the loaded images in the `image_dict` in `__init__`. It's not a good idea to keep reloading images from disk each time you blit them.

Comment: I've just tried to integrate this into the game with no success, the game loads up but the splash screen blits when a key is pressed. I've pasted all my code, would really appreciate it if you could take a look at what the problem is.

Comment: You have understood triple quoted strings wrong. You have used them in places you should use comments. All the code doesn't need to be in a function! **READ [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!** Follow it! Change the code accordingly, then I'll see what I can do. (You will understand why I have said this when you see this code after reading PEP-8 and applying it on this code.)